# Assign integer to multiple characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string, integer, ord

I am trying to assign an integer for multiple characters in a string.

```
def userinput(input)
  @user = input.upcase.delete('^A-Z').chars.each_slice(5).map(&:join)
end

=> userinput("This is test to convert multiple characters in a string")
=> ["THISI","STEST","TOCON", "VERTM", "ULTIP", "LECHA", "RACTE", "RSINA", "STRIN", "G"]
```

After getting this array I want to assign an integer for each character in a string so I tried something like this...

```
=> @user.map {|ch| ch.ord - 'A'.ord + 1}
```

Unfortunately, I only get the corresponding integer of the alphabet for the first letter.

```
=> [20, 19, 20, 22, 21, 12, 18, 18, 19, 7]
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to assign the other 4 remaining letters of each string as well so that the output would be something like:

```
=> ["ABCDE", "ABCDE"]
=> [12345, 12345]
```

Comment: why this `ch.ord - 'A'.ord + 1` calculation ? Why `ABCDE` is 12345? Based on what logic you are doing character to integer mapping ?

Comment: sry that it might be a bit out of context. The idea was to assign the corresponding number in the alphabet to a letter. Thats why ABCDE is 12345.

Comment: `12345` can be translated as `ABCDE`, `LCDE`, `AWDE`. Which one is right? The answer to this question is: we don't know. Your encoding has a flaw: it is not [prefix-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code).

Comment: @p11y: So you're saying i wont be able convert it backwards if i am not using prefix free?

Comment: That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each of the string in your new array to an array of chars then, convert each of the character back to their position in the alphabet like you are doing then concat them into a string

```
@user = ["THISI","STEST","TOCON", "VERTM", "ULTIP", "LECHA", "RACTE", "RSINA", "STRIN", "G"]
@user.map(&:chars).map do |arr| 
  arr.inject("") do |str,ch| 
    str << (ch.ord - 'A'.ord + 1).to_s 
  end
end
 => ["2089199", "192051920", "201531514", "225182013", "211220916", "125381", "1813205", "18199141", "192018914", "7"]
```

Comment: thank you very much - thats awesome and it works perfectly. Gonne have a close look at it to understand it as well. Best, Rob

Comment: @user3215611 please do accept my answer and upvote if it worked for you

Comment: the website doesn't allow me since I dont have "15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick of doing in more Rubyish way :

```
@user = ["THISI","STEST","TOCON"]
@user.map { |s| s.gsub(/[a-z]/i) { |m| m.ord - 'A'.ord + 1 } }
# => ["2089199", "192051920", "201531514"]
```

You first need to look into the magic of `#gsub` from [`gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).

> In the ***block form***, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as `$1`, `$2`, `$,`$&`, and`$'` will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

Comment: also pretty cool - thx a lot for sharing and I am definitely take your advice in looking into the #gsub magic.